# Override the default date separator in .net

Tags: .net, date, localization, globalization

I have a web server located in Switzerland and it is intended to serve both the American region and the European region. When a date is being displayed from the Americas, the date is separated by a period rather than a slash.

In some cases I want to user the period if they are European, in others I want to use the slash. If I specify the format string to use a slash, it will be converted to a period based on the computer settings. What do I need to do to specify the regional settings on a per user basis (the user has to log in and I do know what region he is coming from).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Globalisation in ASP.NET should do everything for you pretty much. See [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bz9tc508.aspx), entitled **How to: Set the Culture and UI Culture for ASP.NET Web Page Globalization**. This should be exactly what you want, as you simply need to set the current (UI) culture for the current thread when the user logs in. You can then call `date.ToString()` and it will return the text representation in the correct format.

Equivalently, you could do something like this:

```
var culture = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-GB");
var dateString = date.ToString(culture.DateTimeFormat);
```

But it's really just doing the same thing manually, and is far less elegant. You might as well make use of the ASP.NET globalisation framework here.

Answer (score 4):

If the current culture uses the period as the date separator, then you can display with a slash using

C#

```
date.ToString(@"dd\/MM\/yyyy");
```

VB

```
date.ToString("dd\/MM\/yyyy")
```

Comment: This is good for everyone to know.  Programmers often use "/" when they are intending the functionality of "\/" (mainly to force the format to use "/" rather than anything else.)

Answer (score 2):

Use a format string with `DateTime.ToString()`, like this:

```
 DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
```

In this case, the / character means "use the date separator for the current culture.".  Even better, you can just call `DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString()` to use the local system's short date format.

There's more help with localization in the `System.Globalization` namespace.

Now here's the trick:  your 'local' system is your web server, and that means it's pretty much always going to use the Swiss format.  So you also want to pass an `IFormatProvider` to tell the system what culture to use.  That would look something like this:

```
DateTime.Now.ToString(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US"));
```

Answer (score 1):

I've not had a need to use it but DateTime has built-in culture information that you could use:

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;
dt.ToString(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("fr-CH"));
```

See [this at MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.aspx).  Just record your user's culture ("fr-CH", "en-US", etc.) then you can do more than just USA v. Switzerland.

Alternatively I believe you can create your own culture information to format dates correctly, but again I've never had to do that.